# performance difference in clojure "for" versus "loop"

Tags: performance, clojure

Both the below functions go from 2 to (sqrt n), and both stop as soon as it is detected if n is non-prime

```
(defn is-prime-for? [n]
  (empty? (for [i (range 2 (math/sqrt (inc n)))
                :when (= 0 (rem n i))]
            i)))

(defn is-prime-loop? [n]
  (loop [i 2]
    (cond (> i (math/sqrt (inc n))) true
          (zero? (rem n i)) false
          :else (recur (inc i)))))
```

Then why do we see the drastic performance difference b/n them? the "loop" version takes almost 4 times as much time (on my desktop)

```
project-euler.prob010> (time (dorun (map is-prime-for? (range 200000))))
"Elapsed time: 3267.613099 msecs"
;; => nil
project-euler.prob010> (time (dorun (map is-prime-loop? (range 200000))))
"Elapsed time: 12961.190032 msecs"
;; => nil
```

Comment: Well in one you use equals and in the other you use the zero? predicate.  so that is one thing that is different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such micro-benchmarks are usually pointless since they don't account for a variety of factors that can influence performance of a specific piece of code (e.g. JVM warmup, optimizations, ...). You should use a benchmarking library like [criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium) if you want to attain reliable results.

That being said, your two versions have a few major differences that will be reflected in the results:

- `for` creates a lazy sequence whose maintenance cost is higher than what is done in `loop/recur`.
- the `loop` version calculates `(Math/sqrt (inc n))` on every iteration, the `for` version only once.
- `zero?` has one level of indirection more than `(= 0 ...)`.

Obviously, the compiler might be able to optimize these away, but there are many more factors that can change the outcome (Java version, OpenJDK vs. Oracle, Clojure version, ...). So, here the results of my benchmark run using Clojure 1.6.0 on Oracle JDK 1.7.0_67:

```
(criterium.core/quick-bench (mapv is-prime-for? (range 200000)))
Evaluation count : 6 in 6 samples of 1 calls.
             Execution time mean : 1.942423 sec
    Execution time std-deviation : 36.768207 ms
   Execution time lower quantile : 1.912171 sec ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 1.984463 sec (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 8.986692 ns

(criterium.core/quick-bench (mapv is-prime-loop? (range 200000)))
Evaluation count : 6 in 6 samples of 1 calls.
             Execution time mean : 724.077492 ms
    Execution time std-deviation : 5.695680 ms
   Execution time lower quantile : 716.547992 ms ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 730.173992 ms (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 8.986692 ns
```

So, on my machine, the `loop` version is about 3x faster than the `for` one.

Comment: Thanks! i understand and observe similar results

Comment: Also, thanks for the pointer to [criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium)